# Unable to display and update select based on dynamically created and remove content jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
/*creates phoens dynamically*/
var phone = 0;
function add_phone() {
    phone++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+phone);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+phone;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone ( '+phone+' )</span><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a[]" value="" placeholder="Type"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="b[]" value="" placeholder="Model"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c[]" value="" placeholder="Color"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <select class="form-control" name="d[]"><option value="">Year</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_phone('+ phone +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
    
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
    $('#phone_picker').append('<option value="phone-'+phone+'">Phone: ' +phone+'</option>');
}
   function remove_phone(rid) {
    $("#phone_picker option[value='phone-"+phone+"']").remove();
    $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
   }
   
/*Add details about phone added here*/
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control' title='Phone' id='phone_picker_dynamic'><option selected disabled>---</option></select> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 1'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 2'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
   $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
   i--;
   }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Add Phone-->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Phone Information</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     
     <div id="education_fields">
             
    </div>
     
 
     <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
           <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Add Phone.</span>
           <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="add_phone();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <!--Individual phone information-->
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
       <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone selected additional details.</span>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
         #
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Phone
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Type
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Carrier
        </th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>
        1
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="form-control" title="Phone" id="phone_picker">
             <option selected disabled>---</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder='field 1' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder='field 2' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
       </tr>
                      <tr id='addr1'></tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Phone</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Phone</a>
  </div>
```

Trying to accomplish the following sequence of steps:
1. A section for entering information about a "Phone" is added when clicking the "+" green button.
2. The phone count(For Example: Phone 1) when dynamically added will be reflected onto the "phone picker" select in table below.
3. User can then select which phone (It is? Phone 1 or 2 etc) to complete information (Each detail about a phone is a row in the table)
4.When adding a new row, the phone(s) added should be reflected on the dynamic row as well and if phone is remove it should also reflect change that "Phone 2" is removed.
5.If any of the "phone information" after being added is removed, then change should reflect on the phone picker select.

So far this is what I have. I'm having difficulties displaying the "phone section number" on the phone picker select and also if I remove section phone picker doesn't reflect change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*creates phoens dynamically*/

var phoneList = [];

function add_phone() {
  var index = phoneList.length+1;
    phoneList.push('phone: '+index);
    var divtest = '<div class="form-group removeclass'+index+'">'+
    '<span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone ( '+index+' )</span>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
    '<div class="form-group">'+
    ' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a[]" value="" placeholder="Type"></div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group">'+
    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="b[]" value="" placeholder="Model"></div>'+
    '</div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
    '<div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c[]" value="" placeholder="Color">'+
    '</div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> '+
    '<select class="form-control" name="d[]">'+
    '<option value="">Year</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option>'+
    '<option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> '+
    '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_phone('+ index +');"> <span '+
    'class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div '+
    'class="clear"></div>';

     $('#education_fields').append(divtest);
    updatePhonePicker();
}
   function remove_phone(rid) {
     $("#phone_picker option[value='"+rid+"']").remove();
     $('.removeclass'+rid).remove(); 
     phoneList.splice(phoneList.indexOf(rid),1);
     updatePhonePicker();
   }

   function updatePhonePicker(){
    var options = '<option selected disabled>---</option>';
    phoneList.forEach(function(element, index){
       options+='<option value="'+element+'">'+element+'</option>'
    })
    $('#tab_logic').find('tr').each(function(ind,ele){
      $(ele).find("#phone_picker").empty().append(options);
    });

   }

/*Add details about phone added here*/
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control' title='Phone' id='phone_picker'><option selected disabled>---</option></select> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 1'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 2'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
      updatePhonePicker();
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
       if(i>1){
     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
     }
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: 1. A section for entering information about a "Phone" is added when clicking the "+" green button. A dynamically div appears when the green button is pressed. section allows to select the manufacture.

Comment: yes I see its getting added. what's the problem then?

Comment: In the table title 'Phone selected additional details.' if I click on 'Add Phone' and select the 'Phone' select dropdown, it doesn't show 'Phone 1' or whatever div # is created when clicking the green button. If I remove div than option should not be on the 'Phone' select option. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes it make sense. Actualy you need to create an array with phones and update it every time when you add or remove a phone from list.
I will update code in some time.

Comment: ok perfect, i'll see what you come up with to see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: I just updated code Please take a look.  let me know if you find any issues to be updated.

Comment: Dude you are the best man! you are the best! Thank you!!!!!!. Thanks. Been days stuck with this.!!